# How To Make A Full Screen Modal In Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm trying to build a modal using Tailwind in alpine, point me to the right direction on building a full screen modal using Tailwind CSS and alpine js

Comment: "The right direction" would be, look at the docs.

Comment: @Martin - not an option where there's no modal in the docs but there is in the paid version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [TailWind Toolbox](https://www.tailwindtoolbox.com/components/fullscreen-modal)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>Tailwind CSS Full Screen Modal</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  <style>
    .modal {
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
    }
    body.modal-active {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible !important;
    }
    .opacity-95 {opacity: .95;}
  </style>
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center h-screen">

<button class="modal-open bg-transparent border border-gray-500 hover:border-indigo-500 text-gray-500 hover:text-indigo-500 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full">Open Full Screen Modal</button>

<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal opacity-0 pointer-events-none fixed w-full h-full top-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-center">
  <div class="modal-overlay absolute w-full h-full bg-white opacity-95"></div>

  <div class="modal-container fixed w-full h-full z-50 overflow-y-auto ">
    
    <div class="modal-close absolute top-0 right-0 cursor-pointer flex flex-col items-center mt-4 mr-4 text-black text-sm z-50">
      <svg class="fill-current text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
        <path d="M14.53 4.53l-1.06-1.06L9 7.94 4.53 3.47 3.47 4.53 7.94 9l-4.47 4.47 1.06 1.06L9 10.06l4.47 4.47 1.06-1.06L10.06 9z"></path>
      </svg>
      (Esc)
    </div>

    <!-- Add margin if you want to see grey behind the modal-->
    <div class="modal-content container mx-auto h-auto text-left p-4">
     
      <!--Title-->
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center pb-2">
        <p class="text-2xl font-bold">Full Screen Modal!</p>
      </div>

      <!--Body-->
      <p>Modal content can go here</p>
      
      <!--Footer-->
      <div class="flex justify-end pt-2">
        <button class="px-4 bg-transparent p-3 rounded-lg text-indigo-500 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-indigo-400 mr-2">Action</button>
        <button class="modal-close px-4 bg-indigo-500 p-3 rounded-lg text-white hover:bg-indigo-400">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var openmodal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-open')
  for (var i = 0; i < openmodal.length; i++) {
    openmodal[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    toggleModal()
    })
  }
  
  const overlay = document.querySelector('.modal-overlay')
  overlay.addEventListener('click', toggleModal)
  
  var closemodal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-close')
  for (var i = 0; i < closemodal.length; i++) {
    closemodal[i].addEventListener('click', toggleModal)
  }
  
  document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event
    var isEscape = false
    if ("key" in evt) {
    isEscape = (evt.key === "Escape" || evt.key === "Esc")
    } else {
    isEscape = (evt.keyCode === 27)
    }
    if (isEscape && document.body.classList.contains('modal-active')) {
    toggleModal()
    }
  };
  
  
  function toggleModal () {
    const body = document.querySelector('body')
    const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')
    modal.classList.toggle('opacity-0')
    modal.classList.toggle('pointer-events-none')
    body.classList.toggle('modal-active')
  }
  
   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Basic modal components (unstyled) can be found here: https://headlessui.dev/react/dialog

The styled one below is a small box, but with CSS you can make it full screen.

```
import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'

export default function MyModal() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)

  function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center">
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={openModal}
          className="px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-black rounded-md bg-opacity-20 hover:bg-opacity-30 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75"
        >
          Open dialog
        </button>
      </div>

      <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
        <Dialog
          as="div"
          className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto"
          onClose={closeModal}
        >
          <div className="min-h-screen px-4 text-center">
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0"
              enterTo="opacity-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0"
            >
              <Dialog.Overlay className="fixed inset-0" />
            </Transition.Child>

            {/* This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. */}
            <span
              className="inline-block h-screen align-middle"
              aria-hidden="true"
            >
              &#8203;
            </span>
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
              enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
              <div className="inline-block w-full max-w-md p-6 my-8 overflow-hidden text-left align-middle transition-all transform bg-white shadow-xl rounded-2xl">
                <Dialog.Title
                  as="h3"
                  className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
                >
                  Payment successful
                </Dialog.Title>
                <div className="mt-2">
                  <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                    Your payment has been successfully submitted. We’ve sent you
                    an email with all of the details of your order.
                  </p>
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-blue-900 bg-blue-100 border border-transparent rounded-md hover:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-blue-500"
                    onClick={closeModal}
                  >
                    Got it, thanks!
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Transition.Child>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </Transition>
    </>
  )
}
```